# Should we remove the reputation next to the username from the question page?

Tags: discussion, reputation, information-display, question-lists

I just noticed that next to a person's reputation is also next to their username (on the question page).

I think this makes it kind of messy - before this I could clearly see who made the last action on that question.

Now it is an eye sore to have to focus away from the reputation first. Anyone agree with me to remove reputation from question?

Comment: This isn't recent... it's been there for a long time (unless doppelgreener - and all of us - misunderstood what you're talking about)

Comment: If you just noticed it, how big of a mess is it really?

Answer (score 13):

It sounds like you're asking to turn this, where we can see you have 101 rep and Shog9 has 235k rep:

> [image: the question list, with statements about who asked and answered what, plus their reputation beside their name, e.g. Shog9 235k, vasin1987 101]

Into this, where we can't:

> [image: no more reputation beside their name]

In my personal experience, it isn't an eyesore and I don't have any trouble focusing my eyes away from the rep first. The name is a different colour and stands out, so my eyes just travel straight to it. (If you're colour blind I could understand this being a real problem; there limited recourse available on the SE engine for those needing accessibility measures.)

From a moderation perspective it's kinda useful: if something looks funny, it probably needs attention, and this helps us gauge how weird a situation is.

For example, on one of my sites, a 20k user asking or answering several questions in a row is usually not a problem, but a low-rep user doing the same is more often than not needing to slow down and *probably* making problematic contributions. The fact their reputation is on display lets me tell them apart during a glance at the question list.

Answer (score 2):

The rep has been next to usernames on the question page for some time.
So it seems you have simply *ignored* it, like an auto block, which I sometimes do myself with certain areas of *busy pages*.

Sometimes on a website or page I've viewed daily for years I look at one day and notice something I had not previously noticed (which I know has not just been added etc).
Whether it's useful or not is another matter.

So now you notice it you feel it's distracting, which is completely understandable, but I suggest just giving yourself time to adjust to now being aware of this additional info.
You might find it useful knowing if the question is from a high or low rep user etc. I don't read all questions, and sometimes choose to browse a certain question based on rep + title.

Even if you don't find it useful, once this new info becomes more familiar to you and you're used to it being there, then you will slowly start to ignore it again.